# background image not set , its display in top

Tags: flutter

```
 background is not set, its display top of the screen ..
background is not set, its display top of the screen ..
```

background is not set, its display top of the screen ..
background is not set, its display top of the screen ..

My code is given below please check and show me where its gone wrong ....

My code is given below please check and show me where its gone wrong ....
My code is given below please check and show me where its gone wrong ....

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(),
    body: new SingleChildScrollView(
      child: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

          children: <Widget>[
            new Image.asset(
              'assets/shopping.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              color: Colors.black54,
              colorBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
            ),

            new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
              child: new Row(

                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new InkWell(
                    onTap: () {

                    },
                    child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new CircleAvatar(
                          child: new Icon(Icons.access_alarm, color: Colors.white),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          radius: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
                              ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8
                              : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12,
                        ),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                          child: new Text("Offer Of The Day",
                            maxLines: 2,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  new InkWell(
                    onTap: () {

                    },
                    child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new CircleAvatar(
                    child: new Icon(Icons.access_alarm, color: Colors.white),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          radius: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
                              ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8
                              : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12,
                        ),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                          child: new Text("aabb",
                            maxLines: 2,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),),
            new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new InkWell(
                    onTap: () {

                    },
                    child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new CircleAvatar(
                          child: new Icon(Icons.access_alarm, color: Colors.white),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          radius: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
                              ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8
                              : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12,
                        ),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                          child: new Text("aabb",
                            maxLines: 2,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  new InkWell(
                    onTap: () {

                    },
                    child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new CircleAvatar(
                          child: new Icon(Icons.access_alarm, color: Colors.white),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          radius: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
                              ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8
                              : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12,
                        ),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                          child: new Text("aabb",
                            maxLines: 2,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),),
            new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new InkWell(
                    onTap: () {

                    },
                    child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new CircleAvatar(
                          child: new Icon(Icons.access_alarm, color: Colors.white),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          radius: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
                              ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8
                              : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12,
                        ),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                          child: new Text("aabb",
                            maxLines: 2,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  new InkWell(
                    onTap: () {

                    },
                    child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new CircleAvatar(
                          child: new Icon(Icons.access_alarm, color: Colors.white),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          radius: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
                              ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8
                              : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12,
                        ),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                          child: new Text("aabb",
                            maxLines: 2,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),),
            new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new InkWell(
                    onTap: () {

                    },
                    child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new CircleAvatar(
                          child: new Icon(Icons.access_alarm, color: Colors.white),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          radius: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
                              ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8
                              : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12,
                        ),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                          child: new Text("aabb",
                            maxLines: 2,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  new InkWell(
                    onTap: () {

                    },
                    child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new CircleAvatar(
                          child: new Icon(Icons.access_alarm, color: Colors.white),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          radius: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
                              ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8
                              : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12,
                        ),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                          child: new Text("aabb",
                            maxLines: 2,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),),
            new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new InkWell(
                    onTap: () {

                    },
                    child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new CircleAvatar(
                          child: new Icon(Icons.access_alarm, color: Colors.white),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          radius: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
                              ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8
                              : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12,
                        ),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                          child: new Text("aabb",
                            maxLines: 2,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  new InkWell(
                    onTap: () {

                    },
                    child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new CircleAvatar(
                          child: new Icon(Icons.access_alarm, color: Colors.white),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          radius: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
                              ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8
                              : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12,
                        ),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                          child: new Text("aabb",
                            maxLines: 2,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),),
          ],

        ),
      ),
    )

  );
}
```

}

Comment: please write a proper question

Comment: background image is not set, its display top of the screen ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your SingleChildScrollView in a Stack and then you can display the image in the background of your SingleChildScrollView

```
 return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(),
        body: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                image: new DecorationImage(
                  image: new AssetImage("assets/shopping.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new YourSingleChildScrollView(),
          ],
        ));
```

[image]

Comment: can I make the background darken